# Zebra GK420d label printer hangs

Tags: printer

We have some Zebra GK420d printers, and one of them gone mad today. The problem is that printer hangs on any attempt to feed it's media (when printing from PC or just pressing the Feed button on device). It just pushes the media out for about an inch and stops. After this, it doesn't react when I'm pushing it's Feed button, spooler reports an error, web-interface becomes inaccessible. But the LEDs on NIC still blinking, and main LED becomes red when cover is open and turns back green when closed. After reboot, I can access the printer's web-interface again (there are no error messages, maybe because they are deleted on reboot), until next attempt to feed.

So, is there a way to fix the problem? Thanks for any help.

Comment: First thing I'd do is look carefully for a piece of paper caught inside, either hanging up the sheet or mucking up a switch.

Comment: @DanH Yes, I've looking for something jammed inside, but there is nothing. GK420d is a very small printer, and paper goes very short way (there is just a roller that pulls paper out)

Comment: Have you looked for a sensor switch or photocell in the paper path that may be somehow awry?  It sounds like the printer is deciding that the paper is jammed when it isn't, due to some sort of sensor.

Comment: If you're talking about that metal and plastic shiny bar under the top cover, it looks good. Also, I've played a bit with other printer, it acts other way when I tried to reproduce possible error conditions: it doesn't stop so quickly, turns the red light on and (surprise) doesn't hangs.

Comment: Okay, I think it's better to send this printer to customer service

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem with one of ours. Did you find a solution? Thanks!